# SMTP log anonymize script

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I have a SMTP log with records in the format below:

```
6,222.3.4.5,3040,100.2.3.4,25,UNKNOWN,0,1,……,9337bc-929a-34c0-29a8-b3a89c834b29  ,protocol,SMTP   ,745663746,STATUS-COMPLETE ,VALID
6,222.3.4.5,3040,100.2.3.4,25,UNKNOWN,0,1,……,9337bc-929a-34c0-29a8-b3a89c834b29  ,date,Wed, 12 Mar 2014 00:08:44 +0100     ,745663746,STATUS-COMPLETE ,VALID
6,222.3.4.5,3040,100.2.3.4,25,UNKNOWN,0,1,……,9337bc-929a-34c0-29a8-b3a89c834b29  ,from,example@gmail.com  ,745663746,STATUS-COMPLETE ,VALID
6,222.3.4.5,3040,100.2.3.4,25,UNKNOWN,0,1,……,9337bc-929a-34c0-29a8-b3a89c834b29  ,to,john@client.com,745663746,STATUS-COMPLETE ,VALID
6,222.3.4.5,3040,100.2.3.4,25,UNKNOWN,0,1,……,9337bc-929a-34c0-29a8-b3a89c834b29  ,subject,12 skills every lawyer must muster     ,745663746,STATUS-COMPLETE ,VALID
6,222.3.4.5,3040,100.2.3.4,25,UNKNOWN,0,1,……,9337bc-929a-34c0-29a8-b3a89c834b29  ,received,from [222.3.4.5] by uwl-vsd-v003.client.com with ESMTP (client SMTP Relay); Wed, 2 Mar 2013 00:06:14 +0100 from MDN-RGE-V002.client.com ([333.4.5.6]) by mdn-cbd-v001.fal.client.com (PGP Universal service); Wed, 12 Mar 2014 00:05:19 +0100 from mail-ea5-p203.google.com (HELO mail-ea5-p203.google.com) (444.5.6.7) by server-2.tower-92.example.com with RC4-SHA encrypted SMTP; 11 Mar 2014 23:06:11 -0000 from mail-ea5-p203.google.com with SMTP id I6ysd382736td.92 for <john@client>; Tues, 11 Mar 2014 16:06:10 -0700 (PDT) from nicsender ([555.6.7.8]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id 87sm453982eeh.12.2014.03.11.16.06.08 for <john@client.com> (version=TLSv1cipher=LDSE-RSA-UED253-SHAbits=128/128); Tues, 11 Mar 2014 16:06:09 -0700 (PDT),745663746,STATUS-COMPLETE ,VALID
```

I am trying to write a bash script that anonymizes the email address in such a way that it replaces every distinct domain within the email address in the log file to a certain random string, e.g 
user@domain1.com gets replaced by a 234623@23423234.com
user@domain1.com gets replaced by a 232342@23423234.com
user@domain2.com gets replaced by a 232342@43534678.com
The script would keep the domain lookups in a separate file.

Can someone please give me some pointers on how this could be done?

Comment: Does the same user in a domain have to replaced by the same random string as well or can that part be random from occurrence to occurrence? Does it have to be shell scripting only?

Comment: Hi, yes the user gets replaced by a random string but the random string doesn't have to map to unique usernames.

Comment: I asked two questions in one comment, you didn't answer the second one.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind is to take the @domain.com portions of the log file and simply use `md5sum` or `sha1sum` to mask the original values with a MD5 or SHA1 string instead. This demonstrates the mechanism.

```
$ echo -n abc.com | md5sum 
929ba26f492f86d4a9d66a080849865a  -

$ echo -n 123.com | md5sum 
cbff36039c3d0212b3e34c23dcde1456  -
```

The same mechanism could be applied to the usernames as well, i.e. the left side of the <kbd>@</kbd>.

Another method that comes to mind if you truly just want 0-9 digits is to use the above method and then run the output through `tr` to translate everything to 0-9 digits.

```
$ echo -n abc.com | md5sum | tr -dc '0-9'
92926492864966080849865

$ echo -n 123.com | md5sum | tr -dc '0-9'
3603930212334231456
```

#### Random strings

If you want to generate a random string of 0-9 digits you can use several of the methods described in this article, titled: [10 Ways to Generate a Random Password from the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/).

#### *Examples*

*Using tr + head*

```
$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc 0-9 | head -c${1:-10};echo;
1294624186

$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc 0-9 | head -c${1:-16};echo;
9716679462199400
```

*Using tr + fold*

```
$ tr -cd '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w10 | head -n1
6503251969

$ tr -cd '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w16 | head -n1
6629563424656680
```

Comment: Using the md5sum would make it trivial to confirm any guess someone might have about the domain of the email.

Comment: @Anthon - true, not sure what the intent is with the quality of the masking.